# How to specify hardware requirement through code?

Tags: android, uses-feature

I have an android application which has a provision to controls calls ie, allow or block specific  incoming & outgoing phone calls.Here is part of manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
     <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <application>
        </activities>
        </services>
        <receiver android:name="xxxx.xxxx.ReceiverOutGoingCall" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="xxxx.xxxx.ReceiverIncomingCall" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This application does not show for some devices in Google play.After a long time search I understood that it is due to `<uses-feature>` hardware requirements. No i want to remove the required hardware features for phone calls from manifest and check them from code.

Some tablets which does not have a Phone Call functionality does not show my application.So i want to make my application available to these tablets which lacks the required hardware.How can i achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some permissions automatically impy feature requirements.**

This is what the API Guides says:
["For any of the permissions below, you can disable filtering based on the implied feature by explicitly declaring the implied feature explicitly, in a  element, with an android:required="false" attribute."](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions)

Your permissions impliy the features `android.hardware.wifi`, `android.hardware.location.network`, `android.hardware.location.gps`, `android.hardware.location` and `android.hardware.telephony`.

You set only two of them to `android:required="false"`. So you might try to set the other permissions to not required, too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to add permissions after the application is installed. Perhaps you can release 2 APKs. One for mobile devices and one for tablets.

Comment: OrhanC1,I said the case of Tablets as an example.I want to make my application work/show for All Devices even though they have not the required hardware for making calls.

Comment: I understand. I used tablets as an example too. If you want your app to show for things that can't use certain permissions, you need an app that doesn't use those permissions.

Comment: Is there any problem occur if I remove  <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" /> from manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to check if phone functionality is available :

```
    public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE;
}
```

Comment: birdy,I said the case of Tablets as an example.I want to make my application work/show  for all device even though they have not the required hardware for  making calls.